# Get the correct label of an empty input

Tags: jquery, validation, input, label

Friends,

I have a form as below;

```
<form method="post" id="contact_form" action="">
<label for="name">Name</label>
<input type="text" name="name"  id="name" />

<label for="email">Email</label>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" />

<label for="purpose">Purpose</label>
<input type="text" name="purpose" id="purpose"  />                              

    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/> 
</form>
```

When I submit the form, I want to identify and add a class called 'error' for only the labels of inputs which having empty values using jQuery.

Please help me short this problem.

Thanks and regards,
Rushenn.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: If you're submitting the form, the page will have been torn down and replaced by the result of the form submission (unless you're submitting it via ajax with code you haven't shown us). If you provide a more complete explanation of the problem and how you've tried to address it, we may be able to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.homework {
   color: red;
}
```

```
$('#contact_form').submit(function(){ // listen to the submit event
    var err = 0;  // define a varible with initial value of 0
    $('input[type=text]', this).each(function(){ // iterate through the text inputs
       var val = $.trim(this.value); // trim and store the value
       // if the value is empty add a class to the previous label otherwise remove it(is it has)
       $(this).prev().toggleClass('homework', !val ); 
       if (!val) err++; // if the value is empty add 1 to the err variable  
    })
    return !err; // return false if there is one or more empty field(s)
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this works fine as expected. But I don't  understand the way it works. I'm new to jQuery, I would appreciate if you can explain me this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#contact_form').submit(function() {
    $(this).find("input:text").each(function() {
        if ($.trim($(this).val()) == '') {
            $(this).css({ border: "2px red solid" });
            return false;
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('form#contact_form').submit(function(){
    if($('#name').val() == ''){
        $('label[for="name"]').addClass('error');
        return false;
    } else if($('#email').val() == ''){
        $('label[for="email"]').addClass('error');
        return false;
    } else if($('#purpose').val() == ''){
        $('label[for="purpose"]').addClass('error');
        return false;
    }
    return true;
});
```