# how to check input type = "text" in formcollection are blank or filled through jquery in minimum line

Tags: jquery

i have form collection and 5 input type = "text" with different Id and 1 submit button like

```
<form id="frmSubmitSupplier" method="post">
 <input type="text" id="txtCompanyName" name="companyname" />     
<input type="text" id="txtFirstName" name="firstname" />   
 <input type="text" id="txtLastName" name="lastname" />
<input type="text" id="txtAdd1" name="address1" />
 <input type="text" id="txtCity" name="city" />
<input id="btnSupplierSave" type="submit" value="Save"/>
</form>
```

in jquery code i want to put if condition for all blank textboxes like

```
$('#frmSubmitSupplier').live('submit', function (e) {
  i want to check here that if all textboxes are empty then any alert but in only single line.. how to check
});
```

Comment: Why -1 .. please give me reason.. i am just new to jquery...

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13776250/get-the-correct-label-of-an-empty-input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it in a single line, unless you want it to be unreeadable. You have to iterate over all input's and check their value.

CSS:

```
.error {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

JS:

```
$('#frmSubmitSupplier').live('submit', function (e) {
    var error = false;
    $(this).find('input[type="text"]').each(function(i, v) {
        if($(v).val() == "") {
            $(v).addClass('error');
            error = true;
        }
    });
    if(error) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //or you can alert('There are unfilled fields!');
    }
});
```

Comment: Unless you use === when comparing, 0 will fail as empty.

Comment: I got My Solution Through Ur Code But I have to make a little changes in your Code.. But I used Ur Code 95%... Thank you very much....

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below on submit

```
flag = true;

    $("input[type=text]").each(){
      if($(this).val() == ""){
        flag = false;
      }
    }

    if(flag == false){
    alert('Text box is emtpy');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

```
$("input [type='text']").each(function(){
if ($(this.id).val() == '' || $(this.id).val()==null)
alert("Please fill the empty field");
}
);
```